# DRF - overwriten serializer's create method but the is_valid returns erros

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, view

I am currently figuring out how to make my post request update the data of the entry if the id already exists in the database:

I've overwriten serializer's create methods like this:

```
class AttributeValueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AttributeValue
        fields = ("id", "hodnota")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        id = validated_data.get('id')
        instance = AttributeValue.objects.filter(id=id).first()
        if instance:
            for key, value in validated_data.items():
                setattr(instance, key, value)
            instance.save()
            return instance
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

But the view which calls the serializer:

```
serializer = AttributeValueSerializer(data=item[key], partial=True)
if serializer.is_valid():
   serializer.post()
else:
   print(serializer.errors)
```

returns an error `{'id': [ErrorDetail(string='attribute value with this id already exists.', code='unique')]}` I am not sure what should I be doing here. Should I somehow overwrite the is_valid method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, if you're using DRF's `ModelViewSet` and the `ModelSerializer`, you'd have separate routes for creation and for updates (`PATCH`/`PUT` routes using the resource id), when speaking of regular REST APIs.

If you're sticking to your approach, however, what you need to do is to explicitly declare the typing of your `id` field on your serializer. As is, DRF's `ModelSerializer` will infer the typing/[options of the field based on your model](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0618fa88e1a8c2cf8a2aab29ef6de66b49e5f7ed/rest_framework/utils/field_mapping.py#L219). Something like this (assuming your IDs are integer fields):

```
class AttributeValueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = AttributeValue
        fields = ("id", "hodnota")
```

Comment: Okay, this fixes it. But isn't it gonna create issues of id not being a required parameter? It's a primary key in the model after all

Comment: you can test it out there, but basically, when you create an instance and it doesn't have an id, one will be generated by the model when saving to the database - so the regular flow in your `super().create(...)` should take care of it for you, if it comes to that.

Answer (score 1):

Making API is different in every case.
I recommend to these two.

1. update_or_create
2. restfulAPI

```py
class TempModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TempModel
        fields = (
            "id",
            "something",
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance, created = TempModel.objects.update_or_create(**validated_data)
        return instance
```

I think you can create more restful code for project.
Restful logic, in my opinion, is using various APIs on the frontend.(Case by case)

2. find the data exists by using GET(List) Method on FrontEnd.

   2-1. If not exists Use POST(Create)

   2-2. Else PUT/PATCH(Update)

Use this

```
Mixins(ListModelMixin, CreateModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin)
```

in your GenericView or ViewSet.

Use serializer_class better right this.

```py
serializer_class = TempModelSerializer
```